# SAML - IdP Initiated, Artifact Binding Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-saml

Looking for solution or sample code for SAML http-artifact binding

We are considering to use spring-security-saml2 and our requirement is

```
1. After retrieving the SAMLart from the HTTP request
2. We need to frame signed ArtifactResolve(SOAP) using the SAMLart and send it IDP via a back end SOAP call
3. SP and IDP Metadata are predefined
```

Could you please give me some sample code how to generate signed ArtifactResolve(SOAP) using the SAMLart, your help is greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Spring SAML will automatically generate the Artifact Resolve SOAP call for you (in `ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl`).

Exchange metadata between your IDP and Spring SAML application and start sending the Unsolicited SAML Response (= IDP initialized SSO) using artifact binding. Spring SAML will take care of the rest.

You can find an example of configuring Spring SAML against an IDP in the [quick start guide](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#chapter-quick-start), you will of course need to adapt it for your own environment.

Comment: my ADFS IDP is not able to resolve Artifact due to some issue like WID farms. Is there any way to skip artifact resolution and use HTTP-POST binding instead of Artifact binding.

Comment: Yes there is, you can specify which endpoint you want to receive the Response at using WebSSOProfileOptions and its property assertionConsumerIndex. You can find index of the endpoint with HTTP-POST from your SP metadata. Please see the manual for details on using the WebSSOProfileOptions.

Comment: Thanks Vladi!!!,  I have added below property in metadataGenerator as well.
"<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator"> <property name="assertionConsumerIndex" value="1" /></bean>"